# Search Web Part Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I am using the out of box Search Web Parts.  I am getting a network error when trying to search.

> Error: "Cannot find resource for the request ProcessQuery"
>
> Type: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error.  For me it was caused by my custom JS interfering with the web parts.